# stack error while trying to modify hbitmap data

Tags: c++, gdi

I'm trying to modify a hbitmap to add transparent pixels before rendering it (but that's not the question) and after some googling I can't mak my code to work.
This is what I'm trying:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL, hBitmapOld = NULL;
HDC hMemDC = NULL;
BLENDFUNCTION bf;


hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemDC, bitmap);

BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = { 0 };
MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);

if (0 == GetDIBits(hMemDC, bitmap, 0, height, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    return;

// create the pixel buffer
BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];

if (0 == GetDIBits(hMemDC, bitmap, 0, height, lpPixels, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    return;

for (int i = 0; i < width*height; i++)//i know there's 4 bytes per pixel, it's just to try
    lpPixels[i] = 0;

if (0 == SetDIBits(hMemDC, bitmap, 0, height, lpPixels, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    return;

delete[] lpPixels;

bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
bf.BlendFlags = 0;
bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255; //transparency value between 0-255
bf.AlphaFormat = 0;

AlphaBlend(hdc, xabs, yabs, width, height, hMemDC, 0, 0, width, height, bf);

SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmapOld);

DeleteDC(hMemDC);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

Actualy I'm just trying to set the pixel to 0 which should set black (eventualy transparent) pixels for a quarter of the image (as I'm just going from 0 to w*x and pixels are 4 bytes long).

But there's some data corruption so that when that function exits I get a exception. Then my code is not correct.

I can say the bitmap is well loaded, and I get the good bitmap info from `GetDIBits`.

Thanks

Comment: How about, post a **complete** but minimal example. Plus the data file (image).

Comment: To avoid leaking memory, and getting into better habits, use a `std::vector` for the temporary dynamically allocated pixel buffer.

Comment: what type of exception occurs?

Comment: _"when that function exits I get a exception"_ You seem to have forgotten to paste that exception for us to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I folowwed the advice of VTT but it still didn't work, it seems that the problem came from the `BITMAPINFO` which was not used properly, so I followed the way microsoft does [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx) and it works:

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;
bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.biWidth = width;
bi.biHeight = height;
bi.biPlanes = 1;
bi.biBitCount = 32;
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bi.biSizeImage = 0;
bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.biClrUsed = 0;
bi.biClrImportant = 0;
if (0 == GetDIBits(hMemDC, bitmap, 0, height, NULL, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    return;

// create the pixel buffer
BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[bi.biWidth * bi.biHeight * bi.biBitCount / 8];

if (0 == GetDIBits(hMemDC, bitmap, 0, height, lpPixels, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    return;

for (int i = 0; i < width*height; i++)//i know there's 4 bytes per pixel, it's just to try
    lpPixels[i] = 0;

if (0 == SetDIBits(hMemDC, bitmap, 0, height, lpPixels, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **biSizeImage**
>
> The size, in bytes, of the image. This may be set to zero for BI_RGB bitmaps.
> If biCompression is BI_JPEG or BI_PNG, biSizeImage indicates the size of the JPEG or PNG image buffer, respectively.

So I suspect that you create effectively empty array since bitmaps are typically not compressed and suffer from buffer overrun later.

To obtain require buffer size you should check `biCompression` and then (assuming that it is uncompressed `BI_RGB`) multiply `biWidth * biHeight * biBitCount / 8`